# Is being good at mathematic contests necessary to pursue a career in mathematics or physics?

Tags: soft-question, contest-math

I am extremely poor in solving a problem quickly, which leaves me doing badly in olympiads and other contests. But, if I just don’t give up on a problem, no matter how much time it takes, I usually end up solving it. To have a future in mathematics or physics, is it necessary for me to excel at contests, because these days children excelling at contests have an advantage over those who don’t (not complete advantage, but advantage nonetheless)?

Comment: You can get better at solving contest problems if you want. If you practice enough you'll improve in many aspects.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The general answer to "Do I need to be good at $X$ in order be a mathematician," is no for $X \not = $ mathematics.

Comment: The problems in contests are designed to be solved quickly if (and perhaps only if) one knows a set of "tricks" associated with the solution path.  There are many gifted mathematicians who might or might not excel in those competitions.  And on any particular problem, many would not find a way forward in the allotted time.  So, as @PedroTamaroff wrote succinctly, "No."

Comment: Time always decides the future because it travels forwards and not backwards. But that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: Somebody said that for a mathematician, it is the integral that matters, not the derivative.

Comment: Unfortunately the title has been edited, so it looks like people who are saying "no" are now saying OP could not pursue a career in mathematics due to this, whereas before it read as the opposite.

Comment: @Dr.MV Sure there are many good mathematicians who are not great at math competitions (probably mostly from lack of practice), but most of them would probably not be completely horrible.  I suspect if someone is _really_ bad, that might be a bad sign.  (Though it seems the OP is not _really_ bad because they can usually solve the problems eventually.)

Comment: @Wrz You changed the title in such a way that it flipped "yes/no" for the title question (and makes it different from the one for the body). That's a problem when there is, for better or worse, a highly voted "no" as answer.

Comment: Related [Advantages of IMO students in mathematical research](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4846/advantages-of-imo-students-in-mathematical-research)

Comment: @quid: I wouldn’t say *flipped,* because the original titular question was a different one than that in the body. But I agree with you that the titular and body question should align in that respect.

Comment: @anomaly that is absolutely false. To be a mathematician you also need to be good at writing.

Comment: G.H.Hardy didn't think it was:  IIRC, he successfully pressed to get the Tripos dropped for some time. Not that he did at all badly on it -- he just felt that "contest math" didn't have much to do with actual mathematical research (indeed, many Senior Wranglers never made any subsequent contribution in the field -- although, to be sure, quite a few _did_ do so -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senior_Wrangler_(University_of_Cambridge)).

Comment: I'd say an important distinction to keep in mind is that posers of contest problems _already know_ what the answers are, which is not the situation that exists in research problems.  As already discussed in the thread, _perseverance_ , imagination and insight count  for at least as much as cleverness and knowing appropriate techniques.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Mathematics takes place at different time-scales.  If you can solve a problem in $5$ minutes that others need an hour to solve, you can probably get a good job.  If you can solve a problem in a month that others might need a year to solve, you will probably do well as a graduate student.  But if you can solve a problem in $10$ years that nobody else can solve in a lifetime, you could be a great mathematician.

Comment: I'm coming up to my 10 year anniversary on a problem like that. I don't think I'll make the deadline.

Comment: @MattSamuel Maybe you'll solve a problem in a lifetime that nobody else could solve in all history.

Comment: What an answer!! Mind blowing!!!

Answer (score 74):

It's nice to have awards from contests on your grad school, etc. applications (and it's something to be legitimately proud of), but they have little resemblance to what mathematicians or physicists do in practice. Math is about solving very complicated unsolved problems with months or years of hard work, clever insights, and building off results in the literature; contests are about solving very short contrived problems from scratch with elementary tools under a severe time contraint. It's like asking whether solving crossword puzzles is necessary to be a writer.

Comment: The last line clearly brings out the truth. +1

Comment: "they have little resemblance to what mathematicians or physicists do in practice." Truth said. And referring to the high school contests I took part on, many of the hard problems could be solved really simply and obiviously with some higher math tools from calculus, that we didn't learn about yet. Same stands for physics contests.

Answer (score 20):

Of course, it is not necessary to be good at Olympiads to become a mathematician. Competitions often require to solve a problem in minutes, and don't allow research or collaboration with others. In real mathematics, problems are usually bigger, and the critical factor is not speed, but perseverance and meticulousness.

However, it is not true to say that it will not influence your future. Obviously excelling at an Olympiad looks good for applying to elite schools and securing scholarships. That's not to say you can't get the same benefit otherwise: For instance if you are just not good at being quick, you can instead work hard on your studies, or perhaps even do some kind of research or similar long-term project that shows your abilities.

The second caveat is that while mathematical work in itself is not under as much of a time constraint, becoming a successful mathematician is easier if you do well in school. Doing well in school is often dependent on doing well in exams. Exams *are* often done with a time pressure. So while speed is not a huge factor for the mathematical work itself, it *may* be a big factor in getting to that work in the first place.

Lastly, I will dissent from the disdain of those asserting that success in Olympiads mean nothing. They do demonstrate several important things:

- They set a fairly high lower bound on the intelligence of the person. Though clearly you don't need to be a genius to do well at them, having some mental acuity is obviously important.
- They show interest and familiarity with mathematics. Others have pointed out that the problems come down to "knowing the right tricks". Fair enough - with the heavy time constraint you can't do much else anyway. But consider where those tricks would be learned in the first place: One must have some love for mathematics and capacity for independent study to bother learning those tricks at all. Many people would simply be too bored.
- You can only learn so many tricks whilst avoiding mathematical enlightenment. Sooner or later your mind will start to see patterns whether you look for them or not. As such, the quality measured directly in Olympiads is not remarkable. The quality measured by proxy is another matter.

Much like IQ tests, chess and the SAT, by itself the test seems trivial and arbitrary. But it so happens that this arbitrary measure correlates well with success in many areas, and with good reason.

So, to conclude: No, you don't *have to* be a good Olympian to become a successful mathematician or physicist. But it is not a completely irrelevant measure. You should consider *why* you are bad at it, whether it's really that hard to just get better, and whether you're willing to accept this unfair handicap (and perhaps be driven to compensate by succeeding in other areas).

Answer (score 7):

Terence Tao once wrote a blog post on this: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/advice-on-mathematics-competitions/

The summary is what others have been saying here: no, because Olympiad-style problems require more cleverness and less patience than research problems:

> While individual steps in the solution might be able to be finished
>   off quickly by someone with Olympiad training, the majority of the
>   solution is likely to require instead the much more patient and
>   lengthy process of reading the literature, applying known techniques,
>   trying model problems or special cases, looking for counterexamples,
>   and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Accuracy is more important than speed.  Sure, if you're fast at solving problems, it's an advantage, but math is all about understanding.  These days, not all math competitions are based on time.  So never fear!  Math companies would rather employ a slow but accurate problem solver than a fast but messy one.

If you want to improve on speed, I'd suggest timing yourself and setting goals.  Try to take past math contests within the given time.  Eventually, you'll see a difference!

Comment: What are "math companies"?  Do they sell theorems, and if so, where?

Comment: I meant math companies such as contest producers like MAA or math websites like AoPS or WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 3):

Solving problems quickly may help you in some scenarios such as completions and Olympiads, but you don't need to be good in those to be a good mathematician or physicist. All you need is to be passionate and willing to work hard. In research no one is going to say "solve this problem in the next hour, or you're out." Research much more understanding based rather than speed based after all.

Don't let "being slow" deter you at all from pursuing math or physics. If you can solve problems then that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Solving "exercises" that just require formulaic application of pre-learned tricks (as is the case in most of these contests) quickly or not will likely have very little bearing on any future that you might have in mathematics.  I would suggest reading "A Mathematician's Lament" by Paul Lockhart (https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf) if you want to hear a little bit more (targeted at the educated layperson) about how the "mathematics" that you have been exposed to in school is very different from what mathematicians engage in.

Comment: It was good up until I read "Algebra is not about daily life, it’s about numbers and symmetry."  It was about numbers 700 years ago, and symmetry 140 years ago. Now it's just about algebra.